# Django count column using raw

Tags: python, django

Is there anyway how can I count my paid column in my query? It is possible? thanks in advance

[image]

*The error says : AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'paid'*

```
def dictfetchall(cursor):
   desc = cursor.description
   return[
      dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row))
      for row in cursor.fetchall()
  ]
def sample():
   with connection.cursor() as cursor:
   cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM app_person WHERE paid_by != %s GROUP BY paid_by, paid, category, category_status ORDER BY paid_by,paid", [blank])
   row = dictfetchall(cursor)

   datas = cursor.paid
   print (datas.count())
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) it mentioned about dictfetchall

> Return all rows from a cursor as a dict

So your data is show as a list of dictionary within `row` variable for example

```
>>> cursor.execute("SELECT id, parent_id FROM test LIMIT 2");
>>> dictfetchall(cursor)
[{'parent_id': None, 'id': 54360982}, {'parent_id': None, 'id': 54360880}]
```

if you want to get all the `paid` data you need to loop through the list and access by dictionary key like so:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM app_person WHERE paid_by != %s GROUP BY paid_by, paid, category, category_status ORDER BY paid_by,paid", [blank])
datas = dictfetchall(cursor)
total_paid = 0
for data in datas:
   total_paid += data['paid'] if data['paid'] is not None #access from key `paid`
print (total_paid)
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I added SS above as you can see I just want to count the category of each name if the category is equal to additional then it counts all additional as well as lockdown, The problem is its hard to conver to django ,can you help me with this problem?, it's almost a week since I can't solve this thing , just need any help